# Owl Carousel item is fixed when using itemsTablet and itemsMobile

Tags: javascript, slider, owl-carousel-2

I'm using Owl Carousel 2.2.1 to create an article in a slideshow.
I did these settings to change count of items in different screen sizes:

```
$(".news").owlCarousel({
    items: 4,
    itemsDesktopSmall: [990, 3],
    itemsTablet: [768, 2],
    itemsMobile: [480, 1]
});
```

**But the number of items are always 4!**

This is the sample HTML:

```
<div class="news owl-carousel owl-theme">
    <h4>Title 1</h4>
    <h4>Title 2</h4>
    <h4>Title 3</h4>
    <h4>Title 4</h4>
</div>
```

The real page is here (temporarily): 
http://new.khayyamkar.ir

The page is like this in mobile devices:

[image: The page is like this]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.news').owlCarousel({
    responsiveClass:true,
    responsive:{
        0:{
            items:1,
            nav:true
        },
        600:{
            items:3,
            nav:false
        },
        1000:{
            items:5,
            nav:true,
            loop:false
        }
    }
})
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/YasirKamdar/pen/BYJENy

Comment: Thanks, it works well. But what's the problem with my code?